# Question about Logic Proof

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-verification

Assuming $P$ is a unary predicate and $Q$ is a propositional variable, I'm trying to prove the following implication:
$$
(\forall x (P(x)\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow ((\forall x P(x) )\rightarrow Q)
$$
So I must show that assuming $(\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q)$ and using nothing but the previous sentence, logical axioms, modus ponens, and tautologies, I can produce a formal proof of $((\forall x P(x) )\rightarrow Q)$.

I start with:
\begin{align}
& (\forall x (P(x)\rightarrow Q))\\
& (\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q) \longrightarrow P(\tau)\rightarrow Q \text{ logical axiom} \\
& P(\tau) \rightarrow Q \text{ MP }\\
& \forall x P(x)  \text{ assumption }\\
& \forall x P(x) \rightarrow P(\tau)  \text{ logical axiom} \\
& P(\tau) \text{ MP } \\ 
& Q \text{ MP } \\
\end{align}
Is this proof incorrect? I feel like I may have made a mistake somewhere but I can't see a problem with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct.  It might feel like you made a mistake because this statement says very little (it is very weak).  The assumption that $\forall x ( P(x) \to Q )$ is needlessly strong, you only need that $\exists x ( P(x) \to Q )$.

Comment: It just seemed odd that I needed to go through all those steps to prove something so inherently obvious. Thanks

Comment: Except in some cases, when $\exists x: P(x)$ can be stronger than $\forall x: P(x)$ (for empty sets)

Comment: @5xum $\forall x P(x) \to P(\tau)$ does not hold in empty universes, and we're taking it as an axiom here.  In fact, this statement would not hold in an empty universe.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon That's not as "abstract" as it may sound at first. In mathematics, there is almost always an explicit domain of quantification. So, your theorem would be something like $$
(\forall x\in U (P(x)\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow ((\forall x\in U (P(x)) )\rightarrow Q)
$$ where $U$ is your domain of quantification. You could not derive this result if $U$ was empty.